# Keep x/y axes the same lengths in seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating some plots using matplotlib and seaborn, and the x-axis and y-axis are different lengths as shown in an example below.

[image]

Is there a way to ensure that each axis is of the same scale?

My example code is nothing special, but here is an example:

```
# plot data
plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color = 'gray', s=5) # s controls point size
plt.xlim(-0.0002,0.002)
plt.ylim(-0.0002,0.002)

# add y=x line
plt.plot([0,1],[0,1], lw=2, color='#414242', linestyle='dashed')

sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=1.5)
plt.xlabel(xlabel, {'size':'20'})
plt.ylabel(ylabel, {'size':'20'})
plt.title(title)

sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Using `plt.axis('equal')`:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] and clearly explain what's wrong with the two outputs? (I guess the problem with the first is that axes are not equal in length? But what's the second one's problem? What is the use of the `sns` functions here? Would the problem also occur if you leave them out?)

Answer (score 6):

I think you want `plt.axis('equal')`, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html).

Comment: This seems to work although it does cause a big shift in the data alignment. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? (I put an example above. It seems like the plot size does not change, just the axis bar length).

Comment: Is there an equivalent function for `axes`?